# Import Outlook Emails to MS Access with the "From"/"To" field etc. as email address instead of just the name

Tags: ms-access, outlook

Is there a way to do this? The current import function default it to just the names, but i want the full email address.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: I was wondering if VBA could be used

Comment: Yes, VBA can be used to access sender name/email as well as recipients' names and emails. Generally, SO is not a code writing service, so you'd need to ask more specific questions and show what you have done so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA in Access 2010 to import emails located in Outlook Public (Sub)Folders - Including Folder Name & Attachments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765142/vba-in-access-2010-to-import-emails-located-in-outlook-public-subfolders-inc)